# AVL Tree left and right rotation C

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I need to implement a left and right rotation on AVL tree.

The struct is :

```
typedef struct tree mynode;   // 
struct tree{                    // tree node struct
int value;
int key;
char color;
struct tree *left;
struct tree *right;
};
```

My problem is that when, after the right rotation, I try to access to `node->left` the program crashes with a segmentation fault.
I think the rotation is good, but I feel like if it doesn't save the pointer...I mean I do the rotation but it isn't saved on the left sub-tree.
Right rotation :

```
mynode* rightRotate(mynode* root)
{
    mynode*tmp=(mynode*) malloc(sizeof(mynode));
    tmp->value=root->value;
    tmp->key=root->left->key;
    tmp->left=NULL;
    tmp->right=NULL;
    root->value=root->left->value;

    if(root->right==NULL)
      tmp->right=NULL;
    else if (root->right!=NULL)
      tmp->right=root->right;
    else printf("Error with right Rot\n");
    if (root->left->right==NULL)
      tmp->left=NULL;
    else if  (root->left->right!=NULL)
      tmp->left=root->left->right;
    else printf("Error with right Rot\n");
    root->right=tmp;

    mynode*tmp2;
    tmp2=root->left;
    root->left=root->left->left;
    free(tmp2); //freed old node
    printf("Rotation completed\n");
    return root;
}
```

I use the function below just to check the first 3 insertions, I want a tree with both sub-tree that's why it checks if left or right are `NULL`.

Right rotate is called by :

```
mynode* checkRotate(mynode*root)
{
    if(root->left==NULL) 
    {
        printf("Left rotate\n");
        root=leftRotate(root);
        return root; //to ensure parent-parent exists
    }
    else if (root->right==NULL) 
    {
        printf("Right rotate\n");
        root=rightRotate(root);
        return root; //to ensure parent-parent exists
    }
    else return NULL;
    return root;
}
```

That is called by :

```
...some code...
root=checkRotate(root);
right->left->color=RED;//crashes here
...some code...
```

And obviously left rotate has the same problem while checking the right sub-tree instead the left one.

EDIT :
New right rotate :

```
void rightRotate(mynode*root,mynode*son)
{
    if (son==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot rotate, son is null\n");
        return;
    }
    else 
    {
        if(son->left==NULL) 
        {
            printf("No left child, returning\n");
            return;
        }
        else 
        {
            mynode* F = son;
            mynode* D = son->left;
            if(son->left->right==NULL)
                son->left=NULL;
            else if (son->left != NULL)
                son->left = son->left->right;
            else {
                printf("Weird in right rotate\n");
            }
            D->right=son;
            if(root->right==son)
            {
                root->right=D;
                return ;
            }
            else if (root->left==son)
            {
                root->left=D;
                return ;
            }
            else 
            {
                printf("Error while setting new son in right balance\n");
                return ;
            }
            printf("Generic error in right balance\n");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3386109 I edited my post and added a new rightRotate but it works weird...Can you take a quick look at it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a picture that shows the changes needed for a right rotation:

[image]

The rotation is accomplished by replacing the red connections with the green connections.

The connection at the top could be from higher node in the tree (`F` is either the left child or the right child of that node). Or it is the connection from the tree's root pointer (if `F` is the root node). To keep things simple, the first parameter to `rightRotate` should be a **pointer to a pointer to a node**. That way, it doesn't matter what pointer points to `F`, the code just updates that pointer to point to `D`.

In the code below, the first line verifies that the arguments are valid. The first argument (which points to the pointer that points to `F`) must not be NULL. Also, both `F` and `D` must exist.

An assert is used to check the parameters to simplify debugging. Invalid parameters indicate a problem in the calling code. The assert will cause a debugger to stop at that line (if the parameters are invalid). Going up one level in the call stack allows the calling code to be examined.

Note that node `E` is optional, i.e. `D` might not have a right child. If `E` doesn't exist then  `D->right` is NULL, and the code will set `F->left` to NULL. No special handling is needed for `E`.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
void rightRotate(mynode **parentPtr, mynode *child)
{
    // make sure the arguments are valid for a right rotation
    assert(parentPtr != NULL && child != NULL && child->left != NULL);

    // save the three node addresses involved in the rotation
    mynode *F = child;
    mynode *D = F->left;
    mynode *E = D->right;

    // perform the rotation
    *parentPtr = D;
    D->right = F;
    F->left = E;
}
```

Comment: Ok and when I call the rightRotate the first parameter should be something like : "mynode** tmp = F" ? I didn't get why I should use a pointer to pointer and what I should write :/

Comment: @FinleyAdams In the edit at the bottom of the question, the code checks `if(root->right==son)` and similar for left. So the code is guessing which pointer needs to be updated. Instead, by passing a pointer to a pointer, the function call would be, for example, `rightRotate(&root->right, son)`, and there's no need to guess which pointer needs to be updated.

Comment: where "root->right" is the father of "son" right? In this case "rightRotate(&something->right, F)"

Comment: I'm using "rightRotate(&something,F)" without references to any son but I lose both sons of F when I do this...I have to keep the references like : "(&something->left,F)" right?

Comment: @FinleyAdams I think you'll need to start a new question that contains an [mcve]. In particular, you'll need the simplest possible code that builds a tree, and displays the tree. To build a tree, declare nodes like this: `mynode F = {'F',0,0,NULL,NULL};` Then connect the nodes with code like this `F->left = &D;` `F->right = &G;` Displaying a tree is harder, and that might be a whole question in itself.

Comment: Ok I'll follow your suggestion.

Comment: Reproducible example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64785130/rotation-on-avl-tree-with-full-reproducible-example-c