# Rotation on AVL tree with full reproducible example C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I've been stuck on this function for 2 days, so I'm trying to figure it out.
The code below is my try (thanks to user3386109 ) to make a rightRotate on a generic node.
I think to be close but the problem is that when I run the code the rotation goes but when I print values actually it seems like nothing happened.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tree mynode;  
    struct tree{                    // node struct
    int value;
    int key;
    char color;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
};
//allocate memory, set color, key, value and NULL sons 
mynode* red_node_create(int Key, int Value) {
    mynode* parent=(mynode*) calloc(1, sizeof(mynode));
    parent->color= 1;
    parent->value=Value;
    parent->key=Key;
    parent->left=NULL;
    parent->right=NULL;
    return parent;
}

void rightRotate(mynode **parentPtr, mynode *child)
{
    // make sure the arguments are valid for a right rotation
    if (parentPtr == NULL || child == NULL || child->left == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while rotating right\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("GOing to right rotate\n");
    // save the three node addresses involved in the rotation
    mynode *F = child;
    mynode *D = F->left;
    mynode *E = D->right;

    // perform the rotation
    *parentPtr = D;
    D->right = F;
    F->left = E;
    return;
}

int main(){

mynode* root=red_node_create(0,0);
mynode* F;
F=red_node_create(3,3);
mynode* D=red_node_create(2,2);;
mynode* E=red_node_create(1,1);;
F->left=D;
D->left=E;
root->right= F;
rightRotate(&root,F);
printf(" %d %d %d \n\n",root->right->value,root->right->right->value,
root->right->left->value);
free(F);
free(D);
free(E);
free(root);
return 0;
}
```

In this example the program ends with a segmentation fault obviously the `rightRotate` runs but it doesn't do its job.

Comment: `root->right->right` is NULL. Probably a bug in `rightRotate`

Comment: You actually have *four* nodes. When rotating you leave out the `root` node and replace the pointer that pointed to it by a`D`. After your action, the root node is not part of the tree anymore. [ Hint: use pencil & paper] Also: the rotate() function needs only one argument, the rest can be derived fron it.

Comment: @wildplasser I don't have the pointer to the parent so I need of a 2nd argument...If I don't use it, as first step, I should search for the right son.

Comment: The second argument is equal to `(*ParentPointer)->right`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously didn't have the proper algorithm for a right rotate...

And the SEG_FAULT was due to your test tree not being initialized correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct tree
{               // node struct
  int value;
  int key;
  char color;
  struct tree *left;
  struct tree *right;
};

typedef struct tree mynode;   // move this below declaration for struct tree.
                              // keeping declarations in the right order does
                              // a great deal in making code easier to navigate. 

//allocate memory, set color, key, value and NULL sons 
mynode* red_node_create (int Key, int Value)
{
  mynode *p = (mynode *) calloc (1, sizeof (mynode));
  p->color = 1;
  p->value = Value;
  p->key = Key;
  p->left = NULL;
  p->right = NULL;
  return p;
}

// having a proper way to free memory is very important when dealing 
// with trees and lists.  It would be better if this was not recursive.
// I'll leave this exercise to you.  I'm sure you can find examples on 
// the Net.
void free_node(mynode* p)
{
    if (!p)
        return;
    
    free_node(p->left);
    free_node(p->right);

    free(p);   
}

// Rotation only needs 1 parameter: the root node around which
// rotation occurs.
void rightRotate (mynode ** root)
{
    if (!root || !*root || !(*root)->left)
    {
        printf ("bad arguments in myRightRotate()\n");
        return;
    }

    // take left node, make it parent,  make old parent the right node
    // of new parent, and make right node of old left node the left node
    // of old_parent
    
    // using letters as in graphics on this page: 
    // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_rotation
    
    // these non leaves nodes cannot be NULL
    mynode* Q = *root;
    mynode* P = Q->left;
    
    // the leaf nodes could be NULL.  Only B is needed.
    // but A and C are checked in unit test look-alike below.
    mynode* A = P->left;
    mynode* B = P->right;
    mynode* C = Q->right;
    
    // rotate
    *root = P;
    P->right = Q;
    Q->left = B;
    
#define CHECK_RIGHT_ROTATE   // undef as needed.
#ifdef CHECK_RIGHT_ROTATE

    // make sure the nodes are in place.    
    if (P != *root)
        printf("RR error. root is not P\n");

    if (Q != (*root)->right)
        printf("RR error. root->right is not Q\n");
    
    if (A != P->left)
        printf("RR error. A is not at P->left\n");
    if (B != Q->left)
        printf("RR error. B is not at Q->left\n");
    if (C != Q->right)
        printf("RR error. C is not at Q->right\n");
#endif
}

int main ()
{ 
    // make minimal tree for a proper rotate.  root has both left and right node.
    // - left node has both left and right leaf nodes, values and 1 and 2 
    // - right node is a leaf node. value 3
    mynode *root      = red_node_create (0, 0);
    root->left        = red_node_create (0, 0);
    root->left->left  = red_node_create(1, 1);
    root->left->right = red_node_create(2, 2);
    root->right       = red_node_create(3, 3);

    // before rotate, we should have
    // root->left->left:   leaf, value 1
    // root->left->right:  leaf, value 2
    // root->right: leaf, value 3

    printf ("before:  %d %d %d \n", root->left->left->value, root->left->right->value, root->right->value);

    rightRotate (&root);
    
    // after rotate, we should have
    // root->left:         leaf, value 1
    // root->right->left:  leaf, value 2
    // root->right->right: leaf, value 3
    
    printf ("after:   %d %d %d \n", root->left->value, root->right->left->value, root->right->right->value);
    
    free_node(root);
    
    return 0;
}
```

You can run the program here:  https://onlinegdb.com/HyQAfPFtP

Comment: Thank you so much, if I will have the pleasure to meet you, well you can drink as much beers as you can.

Comment: Your welcome...  I hope you can handle at least a couple.  Drinking allone is not fun  :)

Comment: Don't worry, I own a latin dance school I never drink alone :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the image that shows a right rotation, for the benefit of those who didn't see the previous question. The goal is to replace the red connections with the green connections to rotate the tree.

[image]

There are three things in `main` that need to be changed to make the code work:

1. E should be connected as the right child of D
2. The first argument to `rightRotate` is the address of the pointer that points to F. So it's `&root->right`.
3. In the `printf`, `root->right` is D, `root->right->right` is F and
   `root->right->right->left` is E.

With those three changes, here's what `main` looks like:

```
int main(void){

    mynode* root=red_node_create(0,0);
    mynode* F=red_node_create(3,3);
    mynode* D=red_node_create(2,2);
    mynode* E=red_node_create(1,1);

    root->right= F;
    F->left=D;
    D->right=E;
    rightRotate(&root->right,F);

    printf(" %d %d %d \n\n",
           root->right->value,                  // should be D which is 2
           root->right->right->value,           // should be F which is 3
           root->right->right->left->value);    // should be E which is 1

    free(F);
    free(D);
    free(E);
    free(root);
    return 0;
}
```

The output from the program is `2 3 1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I'm using the other solution but I would like to implement yours because I like it.